# Automounting in KDE-3.5.10 without HAL

Tags: kde, gentoo, automounting

community!
I have Gentoo(amd64) installed with KDE-3.5.10 desktop from kde-sunset overlay. Recently I have upgraded xorg-server from 1.7 to 1.9 and now want to extinguish hal completly. The only reason that stops me is the device detection. I don't know how to get automounting working in KDE-3.5.10 without HAL.
Oh, and K3B too. Installed version is 1.0.5.
The only packages which uses "hal" USE flag are:

```
# equery h hal
[ Searching for USE flag hal in all categories among: ]
 * installed packages
[I--] [  ] kde-base/kdebase-kioslaves-3.5.10-r1 (3.5)
[I--] [  ] app-cdr/k3b-1.0.5-r6 (3.5)
```

and they certainly can be compiled without "hal" flag. But then automounting stops working and when I insert USB flash drive there is no pop-up window. Of course I can still mount it manually, but it feels uncomfortable. Didn't check if K3B can find recording device when compiled without "hal" USE flag, though. But suspect there could be difficulties too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless something changed in later versions of 3.5, kde 3 does not support the new udev approach to device notifications. Kde 3.5 is a legacy environment, and when it was actively being developed the solution for device notifications was hal.

Comment: Ok, I had feeling that it is impossible, you've just assured me in it. Anyways KDE 4.6 seems pretty stable, so I will give up with 3.5 eventually.
Or I shall continue with 3.5 and HAL. After all Sir Arthur Clarke have warned us about giving up with HAL ;)